# Get Execution Time Difference and Display it in Seconds

Tags: perl

I have browse SO for last 30 mins but couldn't get answer, so decided to post question.

I cannot use `Time::Piece` or `Date::Parse` module as suggested in some answers.

I'm trying to subtract two times and get result in seconds

```
use warnings;    
use strict;

$tod = `date "+%H:%M:%S"`; chomp $tod;  #record time of the day to variable
                                        #Sample time 16:55:44
my startTime = $tod;

 Insert records;

my endTime = $tod;

my totalTime = $startTime - $endTime;
```

Error:
Arguemnt "16:55:14" isn't numeric in subtraction (-)

Thanks,

Comment: what part of the error don't you understand? `16:55:14` is a STRING, it's not a number.

Comment: Why can't you use Time::Piece? It's part of the core perl installation.

Comment: I tried using Time::Piece and it complained "Can't locate Time::Piece.pm in library" that's why I thought it's not installed, again I might be wrong but error message prompt me to think that.

Comment: @homer Do you mean `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC`?  Note the slash instead of double colons.  If you actually got what you said, what would be most odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) function:

```
my $start = time;
sleep 3;
my $end = time;

print $end - $start, ' seconds elapsed';
```

In general, it's best to avoid executing external commands with backticks or `system` when you can do the same thing with pure Perl.

If you want better than one-second resolution, you can use [`Time::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) as described in [Is there a better way to determine elapsed time in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656537/176646)

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot I can use time function and works perfectly fine, anyway to not display any numbers after the period?  like e.g. 0.01564 should only display 0, somehow my stattime and endtime are somuch in fractions that I get the subtraction result as -0.01234

Comment: @homer `time` only returns values in whole numbers of seconds. Show the exact code you used that gave you a fractional value.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot my apologizes I was subtracting start-end instead of end-start... you are perfectly correct.. Thanks a tone for this function information.

Answer (score 4):

Time::Piece has come with Perl since 5.10 which was seven years ago, I'm a bit dubious about your claim to not be able to use it and it's really going to cause a lot of unnecessary pain in the long term to not use modules.  You can check these things using [Module::CoreList](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::CoreList).  Anyhow...

You can convert the "HH:MM:SS" time of day into seconds since midnight.  Fortunately you're using 24 hour time which makes this simpler.

```
sub time_of_day_to_seconds {
    my $tod = shift;

    my($hour, $min, $sec) = split /:/, $tod;

    my $total_seconds  = $sec;
    $total_seconds    += $min * 60;
    $total_seconds    += $hour * 60 * 60;

    return $total_seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot avoid to get the time as a string, you can use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) in combination with [Datetime::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration).

Bear in mind you will have to install it since it is not in the core modules...anyway here an example:

```
use warnings;    
use strict;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern   => '%T', );

my $diff = $strp->parse_datetime("23:23:12") - $strp->parse_datetime("23:23:10");

print join('-',$diff->deltas()); #months-0-days-0-minutes-0-seconds-2-nanoseconds-0
```

Hope this helps!